# API for Trend Forecasting Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a list of values over time (basically a list of integers).
Currently the NPM website is down so I can't really search for API's properly, therefore I am asking if any of you know an API for Javascript Node which takes an input of a list of integers (representing y coordinates on a graph) and can then make a prediction of how the graph will continue to flow.

Thank you very much for any responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want to make a prediction. You can calculate a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression), fit a [time series model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series), train a neural network, etc.

The easiest is a linear regression model. It won't be very accurate; just give you a sense of direction as to where the data is going at the current time.

Time series modelling (autoregression) is probably what you are looking for. This usually involves using historical data to fit a model that can be used to predict (referred to as forecast) future values. This involves some fairly heavy lifting with statistics, but JavaScript libraries do exist, like [timeseries-analysis](https://libraries.io/npm/timeseries-analysis).

If you want to create a fully-blown neural network, tensorflow is being developed for JavaScript, but I wouldn't recommend this approach unless you have a fairly good understanding of machine learning. In order to make an effective forecaster with a neural network, you need to be able to properly normalize data and write a recurrent network; not a basic topic by any stretch of the imagination.

Comment: Thank you very much, that does solve my issue, I will probably have a go at time series analysis since that should make a nice first prototype^^